# PHP/Javascript Checkbox to change form action when checked

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, postdata

This is what I got:

```
<form action="invoiceCreate.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="business" id="business" vaulue="yes" />
```

Basically when I check the `"business"` checkbox, I want the form action to change to `BusinessInoiveCreate.php` instead of `InvoiceCreate.php`.

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: with javascript. Have you tried something??

Comment: To not do it. Make the logic branching decision server side instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#business').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('form').attr('action', 'BusinessInoiveCreate.php');
    } else {
        $('form').attr('action', 'invoiceCreate.php');
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eV7vY/

Answer (score 4):

Since it's not specified, here's a simple way to do it **without jQuery**. Depending on browser compatibility you may need to attach the event listener differently, but the general concept is the same.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" action="invoiceCreate.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="business" id="business" vaulue="yes" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var form = document.getElementsByName("myForm")[0];
var checkBox = document.getElementById("business");

checkBox.onchange = function(){
  if(this.checked){
    form.action = "giveEmTheBusiness.php";
  }else{
    form.action = "invoiceCreate.php";
  }
  console.log(form.action);
};
```

Or similarly, bind an event to the `submit`

```
form.onsubmit = function(){
  if(checkBox.checked)
      form.action = "giveEmTheBusiness.php"
  else
      form.action = "invoiceCreate.php";
};
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9FcJ/)