# Submit form to different URLs based on checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

#### example

```
   <form method="post" class="customform" id="customform" data-async="true" data-recaptcha="false">
      <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
        <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
        <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
        <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label>
      </p>            
      <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
    </form>
```

if the 1st checkbox checked it will submit to this action="url"

if the 2st checkbox checked it will submit to this action="url"

if the 3st checkbox checked it will submit to this action="url"

how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP/Javascript Checkbox to change form action when checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815663/php-javascript-checkbox-to-change-form-action-when-checked)

Comment: will check this thank you

Comment: thank you this will solve my problem :)

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about this is by adding a data attribute to the checkbox fields.

Each checkbox can have a data attribute (in this instance we can call it `data-url`) and you can assign a URL to it.

```
<p>
  <input data-url="someURL" type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
</p>
```

**Note:**

- HTML data attributes have to start with `data-`

You can then simply grab the URL for the selected checkbox in Javascript like this:

`const URL = element.dataset.url`

Comment: I will try this than kyou